# How to select a range of dates on a plot R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWguF.png)

I have a plot like this. I want to mark Saturday and Sunday (july 8th and 9th for example) with a red transparent rectangle. How can i select a range on a plot ? I created that graph with a code:

```
runtime %>%
  filter(activity == "1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, fill = activity)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle("When people run. Date")
```

dates are as.Dated with a format:

```
"2017-06-30"
```

appreciate any help

Comment: Something like `+ annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2017-07-08"), xmax = as.Date("2017-07-09"), ymin = min(runtime$activity), ymax = max(runtime$activity), alpha = .2)`. Can't test without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you very much, this annotate layer seems to be what im looking for.